# Export to CSV in UTF-8 for Excel using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, utf-8

```
Below are my code used to generate csv file. 
My problem is UTF-8 characters  are not coming correctly.
even I tried iconv also, but  no result.

PHP CODE
-----------------
```

> $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
>       $db_selected = mysql_select_db('test', $con);
>       mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
>       $qry_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table 2`");
>
> ```
> $filename = "test.csv";
> $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
> //$header = array('id','name');
> $header = array("Id","Name");
> header('Content-type: application/csv;charset=utf-8');
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
> fputcsv($fp, $header);
>
> while($data = mysql_fetch_row($qry_res)){
>   fputcsv($fp, $data);
> }
>
>  exit;
> ```

```
------------------------------------------
Table value:
-----------------------
Id  Name
2   traducción de idiomas
3   תרגום שפות
4   language translation
7   Tłumaczenie na język

Result:
Id  Name
2   traducciÃ³n de idiomas
3   ????? ????
4   language translation 
7   T?umaczenie na j?zyk

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Not sure. Use Content-Type "text/csv;charset=UTF-8" as application means binary data without encoding. It seems the output encoding is single-byte Latin-1. And you might want to write at the beginning of the content a BOM for Unicode identification under Windows: U+FEFF, in java `"\ufeff"` forgotten about PHP.

Comment: Excel is notoriously bad when it comes to UTF-8; your best bet is to probably just generate a UTF-8 CSV file (which you appear to be doing) and then in Excel do a data import. You can then specify the character encoding of the file when you import it... or use something like Open Office.

Answer (score 14):

Try to add following after your headers:

```
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";  // BOM header UTF-8
```

Comment: Did you try it @Sakthi

Comment: It works fine..
Sorry for the late response
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You might want to accept this as the correct answer, cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you origin data are UTF-8, the best way to export data to CSV / Excel readable, is to  converter your data.

```
$chain1 = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15", 'érase camión del niño'); 
$chain2 = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1252", 'érase camión del niño'); 
echo $chain1.$chain2;
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is UTF in your DB, then you need to modify how you produce the document.

In my code I replace a bare echo with a modified one using iconv:

```
// echo $csv;

echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2", $csv);
```

Excel assumes ISO. An explicit instruction to dump it for UTF is what's required. Works for me every time.